# Running a reusableWorkflowCallJob in another working directory

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a workflow yaml file that looks something like

```
on:
  pull_request:

jobs:
  post-to-sheets:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, linux]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout whatever-repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: repo/whatever-repo
          path: whatever-repo
          token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
      - name: Testing custom action
        uses: action/my-custom-action@master
```

Is there a way I can get `action/my-custom-action` to run inside a specific working directory, or would my custom action need to `cd` into the directory itself (and expose a parameter for the projectDir via `with`)?

Comment: There's a `working-directory` keyword, but it applies only to [run steps](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun), so I guess you have to pass it in as a parameter indeed.

Comment: Yup I saw that too. Thanks!